# Clearing a txt file with php

Tags: php

I have a website that when users enter it, it will generate a hash code and after 1 hour it deletes it.

The code was working on my internet using xampp but when I uploaded the files to hostinger the hash did not get deleted after 1 hour, I have contacted hostinger support and they redirected me to here.

the hash code gets deleted up to 4minutes of sleep, if I try making the sleep time 5 minutes it doesn't clear the hash from the .txt

````
<?php
  $time = 3600; //time before the key gets deleted (1hour)
  $key=substr(sha1(rand()),0,24 );

  $key_loc='keys.txt'; //key location

  $myfile = fopen($key_loc, 'a');   
  fwrite($myfile, ' '.$key);

  echo $key;
    ?>  

<?php
    ob_flush(); 
    flush();
    sleep($time);

    $contents = file_get_contents($key_loc);

    $res = str_replace(' '.$key, '', $contents); 
    file_put_contents($key_loc, $res);
    ?>
    ```
````

Comment: This script tries to wait for an hour before deleting the key, but this will most likely time out.  Do you just have 1 key in the file or several keys?

Comment: several keys are stored in the same txt file.

Comment: It is `max_execution_time` setting.

Comment: You shouldn't set `max_execution_time` for longer values. Look for other options, maybe cron jobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be related to maximum execution time of the PHP. The default limit is 30 seconds or, if it exists, the max_execution_time value defined in the php.ini.

You can try to use set_time_limit(3605), but in shared hosts it's unsual have permission to change this kind of configuration.

You can check the max_execution_time configuration using ini_get('max_execution_time').

Comment: the max_excution_time stays the same as the set_time_limit, and it still doesn't clear it after the sleep timer has finished.

Comment: As I said, it's unusual let people set the maximum execution time in a shared host since PHP was not designed to run for long periods. This could consumes too many resources from the server and afect other accounts.

Comment: the hosting just replied to me finally and told me that hte max_execution_time is 60 seconds.
Do you know of any hosting which allows me to have max_execution_time for 1 hour?

Comment: Only VPS servers like Amazon, Azure, Digital Ocean, etc.